# DialogFlow: Give an answer based on a parameter entered?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to create a DialogFlow Response based on the parameter given

Example:

```
Intent:
Training:
    I want support as a $supporttype
```

where $supporttype is an entity. The desired answer should be dependend of the value of $supporttype

```
Response: (if $supporttype=="Gold")
        Yes, your question will be answered in 5 minutes.
```

or if $supporttype is not "Gold"

```
Response: (if $supporttype!="Gold")
        Your question will be put in the queue.
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this? Or do I have to make a web hook for such a feature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a webhook to create conditional responses.

There is a built-in code editor that can assist with this.

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but maybe someone will find this answer useful if you prefer not having to use fulfillment webhooks and you only need to utilize one parameter.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55926775/1011956